# Could you use Muons as electricity (or rather mutricity)?

Tags: particle-physics, electricity, leptons

Muons and electrons are both leptons that carry charge, so could you build a circuit that uses muons instead of electrons? Do substances like copper that conduct electrons also conduct muons?

Comment: Please acknowledge the muon lifetime in your question.

Comment: Electr_on ==> electr_icity. Mu_on ==> Mu_icity. If we follow the same rule, there is no reason to be "muontricity".

Comment: @nasu This is a false analogy. The word "electricity" is derived, like other words with the suffix "-icity", from the *adjective* "electric", not from the *noun* "electron". Indeed, the word "electron" was coined much later than the word "electricity". A better analogy is: electric > electricity :: muonic :: muonicity (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/muonic). Of course, the analogy between "electric" and "muonic" is not perfect, but it's still better than the non-sensical words "muicity" or "mutricity".

Comment: Actually my point was supposed to be that mutricity does not make sense. Muicity was supposed to be more like a joke. Anyway, it is a moot point as long as there is no actual thing to be reffered by the word (yet).

Comment: Actually the word "electron" was not coined much later, the use of it for a particle it is a  much later development. The word itself was used to mean "amber" and it is the origin of all the other words related to what we call today "electricity".  "Electric" was used as a noun too (and not adjective) to mean either materials like amber or the fluid that was supposed to be associated with electrical phenomena.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer, I'll be ignoring the fact that muons have a very short lifetime, and instead talking about how a fantasy version of a  muon, one that is identical in every way to real-world muons except that it doesn't decay, would behave. Real muons' short lifetime would obviously prevent any *useful* uses of this hypothetical "muicity".

---

Muons are unlikely to be conducted through material that also has electrons in it; they would immediately fall into very low-energy valence shells and be unavailable for conduction.

Because muons are not electrons, they are unaffected by the presence of electrons (other than by their charge, naturally), and would simply begin to fill their own totally separate set of atomic orbitals.¹ Due to the muon's high mass, these would be much smaller than the electron orbitals, so even if you were to have an equal number of muons and electrons, the muons would be huddled too close to the nucleus to make the jump to adjacent nuclei, so any conduction would be done entirely by electrons.

If, instead, you were to entirely replace all electrons by muons, then yes, the outermost muons in metals would be used in conduction. However, whether there *are* any metals with all muons is another question; the electron structure is what defines the behaviour of an element, so replacing electrons with muons like this will completely change them, essentially creating a new set of elements. I couldn't comment on the properties of these "fully muonic elements" (but hey, fodder for sci-fi writers out there who need to make a magic unobtainium, perhaps?).

Now, if you were to inject the muons into a vacuum, they *would* conduct electricity through that vacuum just the same as how electrons can conduct through a vacuum in a vacuum tube. But the thermionic effect isn't going to cut it here (you can only "boil off" the most loosely-bound electrons, and the higher-mass muons will be more tightly bound); you'd need some other way of getting the muons into the vacuum.

---

¹The Pauli exclusion principle, which is why electrons fill orbitals like that instead of all clumping at the lowest energy level, prohibits two particles from having all identical quantum numbers. But all muons have muon number 1 and electron number 0, which are by themselves different from electrons, which have muon number 0 and electron number 1, so it's perfectly valid to have a muon and an electron that both have $n=1$, $ℓ=0$, $m_ℓ=0$, $m_s=-½$, even though you can't have two electrons (or two muons) like that.

Comment: Greg egan's *Scale* is set in a universe with 8 leptons with 1,2,4,8,... times the electron mass which all last long enough to hold a stable biochemistry. He discuses the scaling laws, but what is a metal vs nonmetal shouldn't change much. That being said muon catalyzed fusion would make such matter unstable at high enough lepton mass.

Comment: @KevinKostlan I feel like the much higher ionization energy of these "muonized" elements would change chemical behaviour by quite a lot; is that wrong?

Comment: The energy is about 200 times more, but at temperatures 200 times higher (60,000K; about the hottest main sequence stellar surfaces) and much smaller length/time scales the chemistry would be similar. Oxygen would still burn with hydrogen, noble gases are mostly inert, etc. However, it is not an exact analogy because the ratio of nuclei mass:muon mass is much lower. The lower this *ratio* is the more quantum the nuclei are: easier it is for nuclei to tunnel across chemical transition states is and less vibrational states before the molecule breaks apart, etc.

Comment: @Hearth  You've already mentioned that the atomic orbitals for muons will be concentrated closer to the nucleus than those for electrons.  As a consequence, in the "replace all the electrons with muons" case, the nuclei in a solid will sit closer together, so one of the most noteworthy changes will be that you'll get much higher-density solids.

Comment: And @KevinKostlan - And with tauons rather than muons, under comparable assumptions?

Comment: @KevinKostlan Having a mixture of electrons and muons on the same atom would *dramatically* change the chemistry, as you then effectively have two parallel partially-filled valence shells that are each capable of pairing with other atoms and forming bonds at different radii.
For the sake of conjecture: singly-muonic oxygen would still form diatomic molecules, but with four bonds: an electronic sigma bond, two electronic pi bonds, and a muonic sigma bond. Single-muon-oxygen water would be a resonance-stabilized polymer with alternating electronic and muonic bonds ("mu-polyozane"?).

Comment: @AJMansfield I feel like the muons would be too tightly bound to the nucleus to form bonds while there are also electrons in the way; the muon shell would be *much* smaller, and you'd have to remove the electron shell for it to have any chance of interacting with other atoms.

Comment: @AJMansfield Much like how you won't get the n=1 electrons involved in a bond between two bromine atoms.

Comment: That sort of geometric argument isn't a very complete picture of how bonds work; the real question isn't "is there a bond?", it's "what contribution does muon pairing make to intramolecular pair potential vs distance?". Overall, intramolecular potential is usually dominated at long range by the reduction in potential energy available from combined molecular orbitals, while at short range then increases due to both nuclear electrostatic repulsion and to pauli exclusion that threatens to make some orbitals unavailable and force electrons to accept higher-energy substitutes.

Comment: If we conjecture that our n=1 muon's well potential is deep enough to make the muon irrelevant for metal-like conductivity, then the well potential of a combined muon molecular orbital should be proportionally also deeper, enough to overcome some pauli potential and _actually force_ some of the lesser peasant electrons into higher-energy orbitals to make room. If so, perhaps a muonically-bonded pair of atoms would behave electronically more like a single atom with the combined number of electrons (though, with coordination geometry that would make even the raunchiest transition metal blush).

Comment: @AJMansfield I feel like making that muonic bond would require very high energies to overcome the electron repulsion (though not as high as required for nuclear fusion), but yeah, I could see that working. You could have simple muonically-bonded molecules that act like single very large atoms when it comes to electron bond structure.... This would allow some very Interesting chemistry, I'm sure.

Answer (score 27):

You can use any charged particle to carry an electric current. We like to say that current is carried by electrons because, in metallic conductors, there is a [gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_gas) of conduction electrons who are much more mobile than the positive ions which make up the crystal lattice. But in nonmetallic conductors, the mobile charge carriers may have either charge. In pure water (which is not a great conductor), the $\rm H^+$ ions are more mobile than the $\rm OH^-$ ions. In salt water there are many options, because chemists use "salt" for a whole class of compounds, not just for table salt (halite, sodium chloride). Some comments below mention quasiparticles as charge carriers, even though that's kind of a reach from your question.

It would be hard to build a circuit using muons because they are unstable: muons decay into electrons (and neutrinos) in microseconds. The "drift velocities" of mobile charges in a circuit are very slow. However, if you have a muon particle beam in an accelerator or a storage ring, the current carried by the beam is a correct way to describe its intensity.

Comment: In metallic conductors *and n-type semiconductors*! (it's all electrons in p-type as well, but it's usually more useful to think of the charge carriers as being holes, a positively charged pseudoparticle that's easiest to explain as "a place where an electron isn't".)

Comment: @Hearth Just so. I think of the difference between electron conduction versus hole conduction like the difference between the water falling to the bottom of a bottle versus a bubble rising to the top.

Comment: I don't think referring to the electrons in a metal as "a gas" is generally the best as it could lead to misconceptions by some. I think the phrase usually used is "a sea of delocalised electrons"

Comment: @ScottishTapWater The technical term is [zero-temperature Fermi gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_gas).

Comment: Hole conduction is important in several metals under various conditions. Aluminum is one prime example.

Comment: @rob - Fair, I didn't actually know that, maybe explicitly say "Fermi gas" in your answer then so readers don't assume you mean a "normal" gas?

Answer (score -3):

According to Veritasium, [electricity isn't carried by electrons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHIhgxav9LY). Electrical power is carried by the Poynting vector, which comes from the electric and magnetic fields. Of course, electrons do affect how the electric field propagates through a material, so if you could make a material in which muons have a similar effect, you could get a flow of electricity.

Comment: you should be wary of "everything you know about science is wrong!" clickbait. Electricity can be analyzed using Poynting vectors, electric and magnetic fields, or charged particle movement depending on what you want to know. Without charged particle movement we can't stabilize a Poynting vector!

Comment: @user253751 Mostly correct. Electromagnetic radiation is a charge-free solution to the Maxwell equations which has a stable Poynting vector.